# Content from question missing in edit view

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

This slightly older question [Which one is faster in java? 1. Math.max(a,b); 2. (a>b)?a:b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103606/which-one-is-faster-in-java-1-math-maxa-b-2-abab) looks like:

[image]

It starts with a "Hi". However when [wanting to edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2103606/edit) (not only for the Hi but also other small things), the "Hi" is not displayed.

[image]

This seems a bit strange.

Comment: [SE Meta Dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142324/editing-a-question-automatically-removes-hello)

Comment: @DJDavid98 Nice, that explains it. I didn't expect this behavior.